# Kalman filter + MCMC vs pure MCMC for bayesian dynamic linear(state space) models

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have heard that you can use both kalman filter integrated with MCMC to estimate bayesian state space models, i have also heard that you can use pure MCMC to estimate bayesian state space models.

Why would one want to use the kalman filter approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into the details here, while it is technically possible to estimate essentially any model using just MCMC methods (e.g. the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm), these methods can take an incredibly long time for particular models, particularly in cases with lots of parameters and complex dependencies between parameters. This is the case for state-space models, because your estimate of the state at time $t$ is influenced by your estimate of the state at times $t-1$ and $t+1$.

This is why more complicated, specialised techniques like the Kalman filter (or particle filters) are useful. They use information about the structure of the model to more efficiently (in terms of computation time) estimate the parameters than generic MCMC would.